# Thinning a renewal process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Is there any reference of support for the following theorem?

> If a renewal point process with rate $\lambda$ and inter-renewal probability density function $f(x)$ is split into two point processes according to a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p$, then the resulting point processes are renewal, with rate $\lambda p$ and $\lambda (1-p)$, and with inter-renewal probability function  $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$.

[I actually know what $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are]

It sounds to me a very well-known theorem, so I am looking for a paper or a book as a reference since

Comment: Which references on point processes did you check?

Comment: @Did Cox, Gallager

Comment: Daley and Vere-Jones, volume I, section 4.3 "Operations and Characterizations", might have what you want.

Comment: @Did Thanks. It looks like it has. I have a question for you. For two probability density functions (pdfs) you can use KL Divergence as a metric to see how they are close. How can we use KL divergence as a metric to see how close two point processes are?